# TFileDialogEvent.OnSelectionChange GetFolder

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

**[EDIT]**

```
function PathFromShellItem(AShellItem: IShellItem): string;
{Helper function to get path from ShellItem}
var
  hr: HRESULT;
  iPath: PWideChar;
begin
  hr := AShellItem.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, iPath);
  if hr = 0 then
    Result := iPath
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

The code below attempts to get the foldername and filename from an IShellItem.  The filename (iName)  is obtained correctly but the folder name (iFolder) is always "".  Why doesn't pfd.GetFolder return the folder name?  Am I trying to get the folder name the wrong way?

```
function TFileDialogEvent.OnSelectionChange(const pfd: IFileDialog): HResult; stdcall;
{Handle the OnSelectionChange event and fill labels with information}
var
  ShellItem: IShellItem;
  iFilename: string;
  iFolder: string;
  iName: PWideChar;
begin
  if pfd.GetFolder(ShellItem) = S_OK then
    iFolder := PathFromShellItem(ShellItem);
  OleCheck(pfd.GetFileName(iName));
  {Set the filepath}
  if DirectoryExists(iFolder) then
    iFilename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(iFolder) + string(iName);
end;
```

Comment: The answer to the question lies in the implementation of `PathFromShellItem`. Clearly that function doesn't work. But you omitted it so we cannot debug it for you.

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking it was a API function.  Question edited to unclude the missing function.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work. As a point of order, you leaked `iPath`. Read the docs. They tell you to call `CoTaskMemFree` when you are done with it. Also, to check if an `HRESULT` indicates success, call `Succeeded()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code for `PathFromShellItem` is incorrect. You want something like this, inspired by the VCL code for file dialogs:

```
function GetItemName(const Item: IShellItem; var ItemName: string): HRESULT;
var
  pszItemName: PWideChar;
begin
  Result := Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, pszItemName);
  if Failed(Result) then
    Result := Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, pszItemName);
  if Succeeded(Result) then
  try
    ItemName := pszItemName;
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(pszItemName);
  end;
end;

function FileDialogFilename(const pfd: IFileDialog): string;
var
  Item: IShellItem;
  FileName: string;
  pszFileName: PWideChar;
begin
  if Succeeded(pfd.GetFolder(Item)) and 
     Succeeded(GetItemName(Item, FileName)) and
     Succeeded(pfd.GetFileName(pszFileName)) then
  try
    Result := TPath.Combine(FileName, pszFileName);
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(pszFileName);
  end;
end;
```

You can use `TCustomFileDialog.GetFileName` as your template for this code, if you can't actually use `TFileOpenDialog` itself. Come to think of it, why can't you just use `TFileOpenDialog`.

Comment: I do not use TFileOpenDialog because this is part of a component that displays image information obtained with ImageEn as labels in the dialog.  The strange thing is that the last time I used the component it worked just fine with the code (but I see now there is a leak), but today when tring to improve the component to return multislected files the folder name was not returned.

Comment: You can use IFileDialogCustomize with the standard VCL control.

Comment: Anyway, you can for sure use the VCL dialog as a template for your component.

Comment: Yes... I am using that... you assisted me some months ago with it.  Where is FreeCoTaskMemStr defined?  Google comes up empty...

Comment: Look in the VCL source. Anyway, you can use CoTaskMemFree.

Comment: Well it turns out I think my original function was working.... I was looking a library folder called images which explains the problem... But thanks anyway I have improved the function so it does not leak... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your original function will only work for file system objects.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if a folder is a library path and if so get the corresponding file system path?